# How to implement excel formula intelligence/suggestion using java-script or any third party library?

Tags: javascript, html, intellisense

I am developing excel add-in using office-js API. I want to implement excel formula intelligence functionality in html and java script- when the user types formula in input box it shows suggestions of formula and parameters of formula. Is it possible to implement using java-script or any third party library?

Screenshots of functionalities that I want to implement with my input textbox.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Excel already does this. Your screenshots are from excel. What exactly new are trying to do? You want to duplicate what excel already does inside excel?

Comment: I want this functionality in html

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: What have you've tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]